# PHP Prepared Statement not updating rows

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

What is happening here? The following code should update the "dodelete" column for each row where the "id" matches.

No errors are displaying, but the column is not being updated at all, the id's do match as well.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    //Delete the image, first update the database, then move the image to a new folder. 
    foreach($_POST['product'] as $x) {
        echo $x."<br />";
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE images SET dodelete = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
            $deletedVal = 1;
            if (!$stmt->bind_param("ii", $deletedVal, $id)) {
                echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;   
            }
            if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo "Unable to delete image!";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Should of binded `$x` not `$id`

Comment: Did you mean to bind `$x` or `$id`? Because you don't seem to be setting `$id` to any value.

Comment: Are you sure $deletedVal and $id are set and of the expected values? What gets echoed?

Comment: Pretty sure @BillKarwin nailed it. $id is never being given a value

Comment: You should enable warnings in your PHP configuration, an error like this would pop right up!

Comment: Damn yes, thanks @BillKarwin I forgot to change $id back to $x when I did a test. Thanks.Can you put that as an answer please so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my comment from above to this answer:

Did you mean to bind `$x` or `$id`? Because you don't seem to be setting `$id` to any value.

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $x) { // should be "as $id"?
    . . .
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("ii", $deletedVal, $id)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $id with $x['id'] (assuming id is the key in your array).